# During Upload image select images from different folder and preview all images before uploading and upload all images

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I am doing multiple image upload using php-Codeigniter. While selecting multiple images I want to select images from multiple folders and preview them before submitting the form and submit all previewed images.

I have used jquery for previewing selected images. But when I select another image old preview image is gone and I am not able to select multiple images from different folders and can not upload all preview images. Also, after uploading, only last selected images gets upload.

jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fileupload").change(function () {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var dvPreview = $("#dvPreview");
            dvPreview.html("");
            $($(this)[0].files).each(function () {
                var file = $(this);
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var img = $("<img />");
                    img.attr("style", "height:100px;width: 100px");
                    img.attr("src", e.target.result);
                    dvPreview.append(img);
                }
                reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
            });
        } else {
           alert("This browser does not support HTML5 FileReader.");
        }
    });
});
```

view:

I expect to select multiple images from different folders and preview them and user can delete images if user do not want to upload them and then upload all previewed images.

Comment: you can use dropzone.

Comment: If you don't want to use any other library then you have to provide different input fields to select images from different folders.

Comment: Try to store the already selected image name in a separate variable. After new selection use both (Old & New)

Comment: @Devsi Odedra  - I have to first select all image and then upload. But in dropzone it gets uploaded as soon as selected.

Comment: there is option to false autoprocess.